# how to get rid of all punctuation marks/ symbols in a string?

Tags: java, string

I want to get rid of all symbols or punctuation marks in a string
for example 
String str = "\"hello!.?,\"";
the output of str should be: hello

Comment: `clean = str.replaceAll("[^\\w]", "")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use String's [replaceAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)).

```
String str = "\"hello!.?,\"";
String newStr = str.replaceAll("[^\\w]", "");
System.out.println(newStr);
```

For more details on how to construct a regex, see the documentation of [Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).